# Merge dataframes or match columns to obtain new column

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, match

I want to merge two data frames. So the column `Type` from `Data` appears in `Values`.

```
DATA

Name                Type            Code
gabapentine         Pharmaceutical  60142-96-3
Glyphosate          Pesticide       1071-83-6
Guanylurea          Pharmaceutical  141-83-3
hydrochlorthiazide  Pharmaceutical  58-93-5
EDTA                Industrial C.   NA

Values

Name                Value           Code
gabapentine         0,2             60142-96-3
Glyphosate          1,8             1071-83-6
Urea                1,2             141-83-3
hydrochlorthiazide  0,5             58-93-5
EDTA                2,3             NA
```

I want to get this

```
Name                Value           Code        Type
gabapentine         0,2             60142-96-3  Pharmaceutical
Glyphosate          1,8             1071-83-6   Pesticide
Guanylurea                1,2             141-83-3    Pharmaceutical
hydrochlorthiazide  0,5             58-93-5     Pharmaceutical
EDTA                2,3             NA          Industrial C.
```

I tried the options of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right) with `merge`

But I get

```
Name                Value           Code        Type
gabapentine         0,2             60142-96-3  Pharmaceutical
Glyphosate          1,8             1071-83-6   Pesticide
Urea                1,2             141-83-3    NA
hydrochlorthiazide  0,5             58-93-5     Pharmaceutical
EDTA                2,3             NA          Industrial C.
```

Is it possible to use the OR `|` operator in the merge function? Or in the match function? Cause I want to match the `Names`,and if they don't (as the case of Guanylurea and Urea), then look in the `Codes` and finally add the `Type` column.

Is possible something like this

```
Values$type = Data$type[match((Values$Name, Data$Name) | (Values$Code, Data$Code))]
```

or like this

```
merge(Data, Values, by=c("Name" | "Code")))
```

Comment: Why don't you use only the code variable ? How is the name variable helpful ?

Comment: It's hard to know how this differs from the question you linked to (and many others on SO about joins) without seeing the code that you used to merge your data frames.

Comment: Cause the column Code does not always have a value. Just edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

With dplyr you can try:

```
df <- full_join(DATA,Values,by=c("Name","Code"))
```

then you erase the value column, specifically, value.y

Comment: With this the Guanylurea rows don't appear. That also happened with the merge.

Comment: @user195366 Sorry i don't see Guanylurea in your example. Could you show that case too?

Comment: @user195366 Is that what you where looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Consider an `rbind` with `merge` followed by `unique` to remove duplicates:

```
unique(rbind(merge(Data, Values, by="Name",
             merge(Data, Values, by="Code")
            )
      )
```